# How to use text option to change button URL

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a dynamic donation button using input text. Essentially, enter the amount to donate and click the button. The amount entered should be updating the button URL but nothing happens. I'm sure I am missing something obvious but none of the available solutions here have worked (I tried 7). Thanks.

```
document.getElementById("input-custom-donation").onchange = function() {

    document.getElementById("donate-button").href = "https://securepayments.cardpointe.com/pay?details=Donation|30|"+this.value+";

}

<label for="input-custom-donation">Enter Custom Donation Amount (numbers only):</label>
<input id="input-custom-donation" type="text" name="input-custom-donation">

<br>
<br>

<a class="button" id="donate-button" href="http://test/">Donate Now</a>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: At the end of the line where you set `href` you have  a random double quote and plus sign that is causing an error.

Comment: Thank you!! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo, an exceeding double quote at the end.

```js
document.getElementById("donate-button").href = "https://securepayments.cardpointe.com/pay?details=Donation|30|" + this.value;
```

Just as a reminder, you can always use string interpolations to make string more readable, here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("donate-button").href = `https://securepayments.cardpointe.com/pay?details=Donation|30|${this.value}`
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use `href` to set link of anchor tag

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("donate-btn");
let amount = document.getElementById("value");
let link = document.getElementById("link");

const baseLink="www.google.com/donate?amount="

const makeLink=(amount)=>{
  return baseLink+amount
}

function amountChange(e) {
  btn.innerText = `Donate Me ${amount.value}$`
  link.href=makeLink(amount.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input onchange={amountChange()} id="value" type="number" />
  <button id="donate-btn"> Donate Me </button>
  <a id="link" href="www.google.com/donate?amount=0" > Link To Donate </a>
</body>


</html>
```